# How can I rearrange an array by defining the key order?

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array, where I want to define the order of the keys of each subArray with an array. Let me make an example.

Input array:

```
$array = array(
           array( "version" => 1, "IP" => 1111, "name" => "bbb"),
           array( "version" => 3, "IP" => 1112, "name" => "aaa"),
           array( "version" => 2, "IP" => 1113, "name" => "ccc")
         );
```

I want to do something like this:

```
$a_array = sort_headers($array, array("name", "version", "IP"));
```

And my expected output would be (Look how the order of the keys changed according to the passed array from above):

```
$a_array = array(
               array("name" => "bbb", "version" => 1, "IP" => 1111),
               array("name" => "aaa", "version" => 3, "IP" => 1112),
               array("name" => "ccc", "version" => 2, "IP" => 1113)
             );
```

It would be great if the answer will be in less code or best optimized answer!

Comment: And the function, and the problem?

Comment: The function is actually just for an example and problem is actually i need the mentioned output in more optimized way. Anyway i can achieve the output using some foreach loops, but if you provide me easiest way to achieve the given output would be great one!

Comment: Have you looked into [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)?

Comment: Need to sort based on Version?

Comment: Thanks for the edits @Rizier123, I can realize now how a question would be :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

Just use [`array_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace.php) for each subArray to rearrange your elements. Use `$header` as first argument and [`array_flip()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-flip.php) it, so that the values are the keys, which define the order of the keys.

And each key, which is then found in the array (`$header`), will be filled with the value of it (Each subArray, `$v`).

As example:

```
Header / Key order:
       Array ( [name] =>   [version] =>   [IP] =>   ) 
                         ↑              ↑         ↑
                         └──┐           │       ┌─┘
                         ┌──┼───────────┘       │
                         │  └───────────────────┼──┐
                         │          ┌───────────┘  │
                         |          │              |
    Array ( [version] => 1 [IP] => 1111 [name] => bbb ) 
(Each) Array:

---------------------
Result:
       Array ( [name] => bbb [version] => 1 [IP] => 1111 )
```

Code:

```
<?php

    $header = array("name", "version", "IP");

    $array = array_map(function($v)use($header){
        return array_replace(array_flip($header), $v);
    }, $array);

?>
```